# Why the forEach method in Iterable interface is not abstract?

Tags: java, foreach, interface, abstract

When I see the Iterable interface source, it looks like the `foreach` method and `Spliterator` methods are not abstract. How an interface can have non abstract methods? Or is there anything I am missing in this? See the `Iterbale` interface source below.

```
package java.lang;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Spliterator;
import java.util.Spliterators;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public abstract interface Iterable<T>
{
  public abstract Iterator<T> iterator();

  public void forEach(Consumer<? super T> paramConsumer)
  {
    Objects.requireNonNull(paramConsumer);
    Iterator localIterator = iterator();
    while (localIterator.hasNext())
    {
      Object localObject = localIterator.next();
      paramConsumer.accept(localObject);
    }
  }

  public Spliterator<T> spliterator()
  {
    return Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(iterator(), 0);
  }
}
/* Location:           C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\lib\rt.jar
 * Qualified Name:     java.lang.Iterable
 * Java Class Version: 8 (52.0)
 * JD-Core Version:    0.7.1
 */
```

Comment: Yes, Java 8 interfaces can have default methods. Read the Java tutorial, or the myriad of blog posts and articles that have been written since before Java 8 came out.

Comment: This doesn't look like the actual source code. `forEach` should be declared as `default`. And why is it declared as `abstract interface`? What version are you looking at?

Comment: @Tom It is Java Class Version: 8 (52.0)

Comment: No it isn't. It doesn't look like that. Unless you used a decompiler instead of looking at the actual source.

Comment: Neither the class from src.zip nor the decompiled version (using Fernflower decompiler) looks like that.

Comment: @Tom it is a decompiled version (JD decompiler), see comment at the end of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Java 8 you can define a [default implementation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) in the interface. 
It is what `java.lang.Iterable` does :

```
public interface Iterable<T> {
    ...    
    default void forEach(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(action);
        for (T t : this) {
            action.accept(t);
        }
    }
   ...
}
```

Your actual code doesn't refer the Java 8 source code.

Comment: My code refers to java 8 source.                                                             
 /* Location:           C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\lib\rt.jar
 * Qualified Name:     java.lang.Iterable
 * Java Class Version: 8 (52.0)
 * JD-Core Version:    0.7.1
 */

Comment: It is a viewable version of the compiled class not the source code of the class.  Here is the source code : http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Iterable.java/?v=source

Comment: I am seeing the code in eclipse, may be that's why it is showing the compiled version.

Comment: If Eclipse shows the source code in this way, it means Eclipse doesn't not know where the source code is. In the preferences->installed JREs, edit the JDK/JRE you are using. You should have the source attachement button to specify where the code source is.